# tSalesforceBulkExec component exception

Tags: salesforce, talend, data-integration

I'm new to Talend and I have this problem.
This is the error log that I obtain from Talend log:

```
Exception in component tSalesforceOutputBulkExec_1_tSBE
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input stream can not be null
at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.setInput(MXParser.java:554)
at com.sforce.ws.parser.XmlInputStream.setInput(XmlInputStream.java:65)
at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.parseAndThrowException(BulkConnection.java:129)
at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.doHttpGet(BulkConnection.java:615)
at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(BulkConnection.java:439)
at org.talend.salesforceBulk.SforceBulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(SforceBulkConnection.java:82)
at org.talend.salesforceBulk.SalesforceBulkAPI.awaitCompletion(SalesforceBulkAPI.java:256)
at org.talend.salesforceBulk.SalesforceBulkAPI.executeBulk(SalesforceBulkAPI.java:99)
...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Child job running failed
```

I launch a job that through a tFileList iterate on some files in a folder and for every of those files run a subjob. All runs correctly for some operations and this error happens every time in a different tSalesforceOutputBulkExec component. Can be a problem related to the connection?